# Which blender experimental build has the extrude geometry node

Tags: extrude, geometry-nodes

There are several tutorials that include an extrude node but no matter what experimental build I download, including the ones linked in the video, I can't find it. [Here is one of the tutorials I'm referring to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SI8Q8_pOFHU&ab_channel=JimmyGunawan)

Comment: No link ein your question. Add a screenshot of your „extrude“ node.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, it was postponed to 3.1: https://developer.blender.org/T93203

It was in earlier version of fields https://www.blendernation.com/2021/08/18/attributes-and-fields-the-future-of-geometry-nodes-has-been-decided/

Some builds from these times should have this one